# KivyMD TopAppBar

Tags: kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to learn Kivy and KivyMD because I want to make an android app.

But I'm stuck at the first hurdle. I want a toolbar, or as the KivyMD documentation calls it, a TopAppBar.

I'm trying to implement it as per the doc's, but I get an error `Unknown Class <MDTopAppBar>`

I though maybe that I had mistyped something, so I copied and pasted the entire code example from the docs and the error still persists. As far as I am aware, I am running the latest version of Kivy & KivyMD

Code from docs:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDTopAppBar:
        title: "MDTopAppBar"

    MDLabel:
        text: "Content"
        halign: "center"
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Test().run()
```

My code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder


KV = '''
MDBoxLayout:

    MDTopAppBar:
        title: "World Pool Rules"
'''


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I've also tried `from kivymd.uix.topappbar import MDTopAppBar` but just get a `No module named` error.

Any help would be much appreciated

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue. I was looking through the official documentation and saw, that the documentation was referencing version 1.0.0-dev. However, I had installed via pypi version: 0.104.2 (latest official version - I guess?)

https://pypi.org/project/kivymd/

After changing the documentation to the right version:

https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.2/index.html

I saw that there is no "MDTopBar". You will need to use just "MDToolbar" instead.

Comment: **Yikes.** I just hit this as well. Certainly, replacing the location-specific suite of `MD{Bottom,Top}AppBar` widgets with a single location-agnostic `MDToolbar` is sensible. What's insensible is that the RTD-hosted documentation for KivyMD labelled "latest" is, in fact, outdated; you have to manually select the documentation for the newest stable release to view the *real* latest API. `</facepalm>`

Comment: **Oh. I see.** According to [commentary on this issue thread by the principal developer of KivyMD](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/issues/1228#issuecomment-1100962034), the single location-agnostic `MDToolbar` widget has indeed been replaced with the location-specific suite of `MD{Bottom,Top}AppBar` widgets. The catch? This new API has yet to be officially released. You need to [manually install the live version of KivyMD from its GitHub-hosted `git` repository](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD). KivyMD's "latest" documentation is, in fact, its unstable documentation.

Answer (score 0):

According to [commentary on this issue thread by the principal developer of KivyMD](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/issues/1228#issuecomment-1100962034), the location-specific suite of `MD{Bottom,Top}AppBar` widgets is a **recent addition that has yet to be officially released.** Presumably, these widgets will be published with the next stable release (e.g., KivyMD 0.104.3).

To access them now anyway, manually install the [live version of KivyMD from its GitHub-hosted git repository](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD). Thanks to the magic of modern `pip`, this one-liner gets you there and back again: e.g.,

```sh
pip install git+https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD.git
```

KivyMD's "latest" documentation is, in fact, its unstable documentation. This is why we can't have good things.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `MDTopAppBar` into a `MDBoxLayout`, you can try using `MDScreen` instead. That would work I guess. I have created various apps using `MDTopAppBar` but did not get any error as you have mentioned.

.KV code

```
MDScreen:
  MDTopAppBar:
    title: "World Pool Rules"
```

Else you can re-install kivy, kivymd using `pip install kivymd`